# It is unsure if the app likes to support both iOS 13 and iOS 14 for the widget

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension, widgetkit

It is unsure if the app likes to support both iOS 13 and iOS 14 for the widget.

On iOS 13 and earlier, the widget is Today Extension and its implementation is through NCWidgetProviding, but it is deprecated to replace with a new WidgetKit on iOS 14.

It would be simple if the app support only iOS 14 - removing old Today Extension and replace it with WidgetKit. But like to keep compatibility with iOS 13, what would be the best way? Do we need to leave the current Today Extension and add a new WidgetKit implementation on it?

I tried to figure out, no documentation is available. Any guides and help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you target iOS 13, does `NCWidgetProviding` raises a depreciation warning? It's usually the case with Apple, that it's only visibly deprecated if you target the iOS version where the API was deprecated. If positive anyway, I guess `if @available(` is the way, as usual. :)